# Searching for a specific value in Postgres JSONB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres newbie here. I am trying to search a specific field in Postgres 10. The column type is JSONB and I am trying to update a column where `returnItem` is true in `shoppingDetails` column in `customers` table. I am trying this to obtain these values but it returns nothing (no error as well):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE shoppingDetails::text::jsonb -> 'returnItem' = 'true';
```

This is an example of how specific shoppingDetails cell looks like:

```
"{\"shoppingDate\":\"01/2021\",\"returnDate\":\"01/2020\",\"shoppingId\":[12345],\"returnItem\":true,\"customerDetails\":{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"location\":\"NewYork\"}}"
```

How could I fetch rows that `returnItem` that are true? I can't connect escaping the slash and getting this `returnItem` from `shoppingDetails` jsonb object. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

My mistake, I didn't go over Postgres docs entirely. I am sorry I wasted time. Correct query was supposed to be:

```
  SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (shoppingDetails #>> '{}')::jsonb ->> 'returnItem' = 'true';
```

Comment: I am so sorry wasting whoever already viewed this. I made a mistake with my query. I will provide the answer.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question, add it as an answer.